# PLY Issue matching all found token

Tags: python, c, yacc, lex, ply

I want to parse some C files for functions and a specific command.
My aim is to get all functions that use the specific command as well as all times the command gets called.
Thus I decided to generate extra token for that by using multiple conditions.

Here is my lexer and parser code:

```
import os
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

results = []
calls = []

# Declare the state
states = (
  ('func', 'exclusive'),
  ('parameter', 'exclusive'),
  ('httpgettext', 'exclusive')
)

reserved = {
    'void': 'VOID',
    'int': 'INT',
    'uint8': 'UINT8',
    'uint16': 'UINT16',
    'uint32': 'UINT32',
    'TRet': 'TRET',
    'TBool': 'TBOOL',
    'bool': 'BOOL',
}

tokens = [
    'ID',
    'FUNC',
    'PARAMETERLIST',
    'CALL',
    'SEMICOLON'
] + list(reserved.values())

# Start of token description for INITIAL mode (inclusive)


def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value, 'ID')
    return t


# Start of token description for HttpGetText condition

def t_httpgettext_SEMICOLON(t):
    r'\;'
    t.value = t.lexer.lexdata[t.lexer.call_start:t.lexer.lexpos-1]
    t.type = 'CALL'
    t.lexer.pop_state()
    global calls
    arguments = str(t.value).split(',')
    calls.append([arguments[1], arguments[2]])


# Start of token description for parameter list condition


def t_parameter(t):
    r'\('
    t.lexer.parameter_start = t.lexer.lexpos
    t.lexer.paren_level = 1
    t.lexer.push_state('parameter')


def t_parameter_lparen(t):
    r'\('
    t.lexer.paren_level += 1


def t_parameter_rparen(t):
    r'\)'
    t.lexer.paren_level -= 1

    if t.lexer.paren_level == 0:
        t.value = t.lexer.lexdata[t.lexer.parameter_start:t.lexer.lexpos - 1]
        t.type = 'PARAMETERLIST'
        t.lexer.pop_state()
        return t


# Start of token description for function block condition


def t_func(t):
    r'\{'
    t.lexer.code_start = t.lexer.lexpos        # Record the starting position
    t.lexer.brace_level = 1                          # Initial brace level
    t.lexer.push_state('func')                     # Enter 'ccode' state


# Rules for the ccode state
def t_func_lbrace(t):
    r'\{'
    t.lexer.brace_level += 1


def t_func_rbrace(t):
    r'\}'
    t.lexer.brace_level -= 1

    if t.lexer.brace_level == 0:
        t.value = t.lexer.lexdata[t.lexer.code_start:t.lexer.lexpos - 1]
        t.type = "FUNC"
        t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count('\n')
        t.lexer.pop_state()
        return t


# Start of token description valid for all conditions

t_ANY_ignore = " \t§$%&+#-_:.<<|',\0"


def t_ANY_HttpGetText(t):
    r'HttpGetText'
    t.lexer.call_start = t.lexer.lexpos
    t.lexer.push_state('httpgettext')


# For bad characters, we just skip over it
def t_ANY_error(t):
    t.lexer.skip(1)


def t_ANY_comment(t):
    r'(/\*(.|\n)*?\*/)|(//.*)'
    pass


def t_ANY_ignore_comments(t):
    r'//.*'
    pass


def t_ANY_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)


lexer = lex.lex()


def p_statement_function(p):
    'statement : type identifier parameter function'
    p[0] = p[2]
    global results
    identifier = str(p[2])
    parameter_list = str(p[3]).replace('\n', '')
    function_block = str(p[4])
    if function_block.find('HttpGetText') != -1:
        results.append([identifier, parameter_list, function_block])
        print(identifier)
    # while True:
    #     tok = parser.token()
    #     print(tok)
    #     if not tok:
    #         break


def p_parameter_PARAMETERLIST(p):
    'parameter : PARAMETERLIST'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_function_FUNC(p):
    'function : FUNC'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_identifier_ID(p):
    'identifier : ID '
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_type_TBOOL(p):
    'type : TBOOL'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_type_VOID(p):
    'type : VOID'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_type_TRET(p):
    'type : TRET'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_type_BOOL(p):
    'type : BOOL'


def p_type_INT(p):
    'type : INTEGER'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_INTEGER_INT(p):
    'INTEGER : INT'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_INTEGER_UINT8(p):
    'INTEGER : UINT8'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_INTEGER_UINT16(p):
    'INTEGER : UINT16'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_INTEGER_UINT32(p):
    'INTEGER : UINT32'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_error(p):
    print('Syntax error in input: ', p)
    parser.restart()


parser = yacc.yacc()


with open('C:/Users/z0046abb/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/TextLibraryAnalysis/test_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.read()

parser.parse(read_data)

print(results)
print(calls)
```

This is the content of my test_file.txt:

```
int main(argv)
{
    HttpGetText(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4);

    return 0
}

void func2(bla, bla, bla)
{
    something = random();
    HttpGetText(1,2,3,4);
}

void func3(bla, bla, bla)
{
    something = random();
    HttpGetText(1,21,31,4);
}

void func4(bla, bla, bla)
{
    HttpGetText(1, 22, 32, 4);
}

void func5(bla, bla, bla)
{
    something();
}

void func6(bla)
{
    HttpGetText(1, 23, 33, 4);
}

HttpGetText(1, 24, 34, 4);
HtppGetText(1, 25, 35, 4);
```

But somehow not all matches are found/processed.
This is the output of a test run:

```
main
Syntax error in input:  LexToken(VOID,'void',12,75)
func3
Syntax error in input:  LexToken(VOID,'void',30,243)
Syntax error in input:  LexToken(VOID,'void',44,353)
[['main', 'argv', '\n    HttpGetText(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4);\n\n    return 0\n'], ['func3', 'bla, bla, bla', '\n    something = random();\n    HttpGetText(1,21,31,4);\n']]
[[' Arg2', ' Arg3'], ['2', '3'], ['21', '31'], [' 22', ' 32'], [' 23', ' 33']]
```

As you can see there is a error at `void` despite it being a reserved token.
I am not sure if the problem is in my lexer or parser implementation.
If I use the 'lookahead' functionality (part of the function that is a comment) from `p_statement_function(p):` it seems like all token are correctly labeled.

However the above output only seems to identify main() and func3().

Additionally the last two lines of `test_file.txt` should be appended as well.

My first idea was to switch from `t.lexer.begin(state)` to `t.lexer.push_state(state)` so I could return to the last state the lexer had would help here but it doesn't seem so.

Now I ran out of ideas. It doesn't seem to fail because of the global lists I use to store results (I am aware that global vars are a bit risky).

In addition I am suprised by the fact that `main()` and `func3()` are found to be fitting matches other than the rest of implemented functions.

I would be happy if anyone of you has an idea for me.

Edit:
I tried to modify test_file.txt. If there is some nonsense word between every function I can record all functions in my global result list. Though this isn't the solution I wish for.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem you have is that the starting point you have given your parser is `statement`. As it name suggests, that  non-terminal matches a single statement (actually, a single function definition). It does not match anything more, so once the statement is complete, the parser expects to see the end of input. Any token will therefore be a syntax error. (Some of these error messages are suppressed by Ply's error recovery mechanism.)

To fix that, you need to add a start non-terminal which recognises a sequence of statements:

```
program : | program statement
```

The other relevant error is in your lexer. Since `t_ID` precedes `t_ANY_HttpGetText`, it takes priority. That means that in `INITIAL` state, the `HttpGetText` token is recognised as an `ID` something which should have been visible when you tested the scanner. I don't think this is necessarily serious since top-level function calls are illegal in C (even in initialisers of global variables). But you can easily fix it by reordering those two lexer rules.

---

In an answer to a previous question of yours which I think concerns the same project, I said:

> Note that trying to do all this work in the lexer is not generally recommended. Lexers should normally return simple atomic tokens, leaving it to the parser's grammar to do the work of putting the tokens together into a useful structure.

I regret not having made this warning stronger. Although it may seem like a lot of work to correctly tokenise C programs, it's actually not that difficult, and there are lots of examples floating around. A full parse is complicated, but most of the complications have to do with declarations and simplifications are possible if you don't need all that information.

Alternatively, complete open source C parsing solutions exist. There's a certain learning curve associated with using them, but the payoff is the flexibility to analyse program structure systematically without having to immerse yourself in the quirks of C syntax. (These aspects are much more acute if the code you are analysing is C++.)

Comment: How do I exactly implement a non-terminal starting rule to catch a sequence? The example you gave me doesn't work in my code. Sorry for that questions but I am lost on this one.
Thanks for the explanation to t_ID in Initial mode. Totally lost track of it.
Yes I would as well like to use some different parsing solution but I am kind of obliged to use this approach. However I just want to parse those files to gain some information about the content. So I don't need the full range of functionality of existing parsing solutions.

Comment: @doublesobig: it's two rules in Ply terms: one has an empty right hand side, and the other has the two non-terminals shown. The | is used by most parser-generators to indicate alternative right-hand sides.

Comment: Also: You don't need the full power of Ply either. Or, fir that matter, of Python and its standard library. You are free to use what you need and ignore what you don't (until you need it). But it's a lot more convenient to have that entire framework available even if you are just using a tiny part of it. The same goes for a library which gives you a complete syntax tree: you probably don't need every detail (unless you're actually writing a compiler) but the part that you do need is nicely organised and thus easier to use.

Comment: So would it be correct to split that rule `program : | program statement` into `program : ` and `program : program statement`? I receive following error by using the combined rule `Illegal name '|' in rule 'program'`

Comment: @doublesobig: Ply lets you use the `|` in a syntax comment if the two alternatives have the same action (`pass`, for example). But you have to put the `|` at the beginning of a line. There are lots of examples in the Ply docs.

Comment: Somehow I only manage to get main() to func5() as a result. func6() is still missing

Comment: @double That's probably an artefact of the way you (don't) parse the input. Ply does not optimise reduce-only states, so a reduction only happens if the lookahead is appropriate. In the case of `func6`, the next token actually returned by the lexer is `ID`, which happens because of the misspelled `HtppGetText` near the end. `ID` is not a possible follow for `statement`, so the parser produces an error rather than reducing `statement`. All I can say here is that this is often what happens when you try to short-circuit the parse.

Comment: No doubt there's another hack you can introduce (such as allowing `ID` as a `statement`).

Comment: Allowing ID as a statement worked.
Parsing some C files showed that there is still a problem with assignments right before a function definition.
I tried to use the pycparser but it failes due to some reason I still need to find out.

Comment: @doublesobig: parsing with `debug=True` produces lots of useful information about the progress if the parse. Perhaps too much :-( but it's better than nothing. However, I think it's worthwhile to consider tools like pycparser.

Comment: I implemented another "hack" and do a restart every time there is a semicolon in INITIAL state. This leads to a reset of the parser stack. Thus I manage to parse a function even if there is a declaration of extern functions ahead of it.
Yet I didn't manage to get pycparser working.

Comment: The author.of pycparsing is a regular SO contributor. If you ask a clear and focused question, I'm sure you'll get a good answer.